# How to use getSupportFragmentManger to find ListFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a fragment that extends ListFragment, from another fragment i want to use getSupportFramentManager().findFragment() to find my ListFragment i.e

```
DetailFrag detailFrag = (DetailFrag) getSupportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.detail_frag)

if (detailFrag != null){
  // do something with detailFrag...
}else{
  DetailFrag newFrag = new DetailFrag();
  // ....
}
```

// DetailFrag class implenentation

```
public class DetailFrag extends ListFragment{
 // ...
}
```

But eclipse shows an error `"cannot cast from Fragment to DetailFrag"`

I noticed, getSupportFragmentManager.findFragmentById() method returns a Fragment, how can i find a "ListFragment"

Thanks,
Gath

Comment: ListFragment is derived from a fragment

Answer (score 0):

You missed "()"

Change:

```
DetailFrag detailFrag = (DetailFrag) getSupportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.detail_frag)
```

to:

```
DetailFrag detailFrag = (DetailFrag) getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.detail_frag)
```

Edit: Try adding `getActivity()` before `getSupportFragmentManager()`.

Comment: actually in my code "()" are included, i have edited the question to reflect that, but that's not the problem.

Comment: the activity with this code is of FragmentActivity type, so eclipse complains "getActivity() is undefined for this type" ...

Comment: Are you importing `android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity` and `android.support.v4.app.ListFragment`?